# Use awk interactively through a pipe

Tags: shell, awk, pipe

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907238/get-the-user-input-in-awk), I've noticed that `awk` can't read user
input if the file is being piped into standard input, but it does
behave as expected if reading input from a file given as a command
line parameter.

For instance, if you have the following BEGIN block in your `awk` script:

```
BEGIN {
    printf "Enter input: "
    getline var < "-"
}
```

If you run it like `awk -f ./script.awk file.txt`, it will ask prompt
for user input, and then will proceed processing `file.txt`. However,
if you run like `cat file.txt | awk -f ./script.awk`, I suppose awk
will interpret what it is getting from the pipe as the user's input
(so `getline` will fill `var` with the first line of `file.txt`).

Is there a way to make `awk` behave like it is reading from a file, but being used in a pipe?

I can use a temporary file, sure, but this is far from elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a temporary file, you could use of your shell's support for
process substitution (this assumes `bash`, `zsh` or some implementations of `ksh` (the feature was introduced by ksh88)):

```
awk -f ./script.awk <(cat file.txt)
```

This will provide `awk` a file name in place of the `<(...)` construct
which, when read, will contain the output of the enclosed command.

Comment: I'm using `zsh`, and this solution also works with it without any modification.

Answer (score 5):

Process substitution would work in simple cases but here is a generic way allowing to dialog with the console user while still processing piped data:

```
BEGIN {
    printf "Enter input: " > "/dev/tty"
    getline var < "/dev/tty"
    print var
}
```

Comment: Nice. I generally avoid touching `/dev/tty` (because what if the user wants to use redirects?), but, in this case, this looks completely adequate.

Answer (score 2):

If that fits your workflow, you can make awk itself open the pipe. You can't do that for an `ARGV` element, so you won't get awk's automatic iteration on the lines read from the pipe. Instead awk will read from the files passed as command line arguments, or from standard input if there were no file arguments.

```
{
    printf "Enter input: "
    getline var
    while (("cat file.txt" | getline) > 0) { … }
}
```

This structure doesn't fit your toy example well, but I'm mentioning it because it might fit your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

if your system supports the `/dev/fd/[num]` links or your `awk` is GNU `awk`, this should probably work where `awk -f ./script.awk file.txt` does:

```
{ some_cmd | 3<&0 <&4 4<&- awk -f ./script.awk /dev/fd/3; } 4<&0
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - oh, duh. thanks again, sc.